# How to implement case insensitive search for email in Azure Search

Tags: azure, lucene, azure-cognitive-search, analyzer

I am using Azure Search in one of my projects and have a requirement to search case insensitive email addresses.
E.g. emusk@gmail.com, EMusk@gmail.com, eMusk@gmail.com should all return the same result.
I am using custom analyzer while creating an index (uax_url_email) 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/rest/api/searchservice/custom-analyzers-in-azure-search#AnalyzerTable

Here is the portion of index

```
            [{
                "name": "Username",
                "type": "Edm.String",
                "searchable": true,
                "filterable": false,
                "sortable": false,
                "facetable": false,
                "analyzer": "email_analyzer"
            },              

        ],
        "analyzers": [
            {
                "name": "email_analyzer",
                "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.CustomAnalyzer",
                "tokenizer": "uax_url_email",
                "tokenFilters": ["lowercase"]
            }]
```

But the search is not working for Emusk@gmail.com. Can anyone please assist?

Answer (score 0):

I created an index with the same custom analyzer and got back the expected results with a case-insensitive match. I used a simple query - `search=EMusk@gmail.com`

Can you share the exact query being used?

You can also check if the field is getting analyzed and indexed properly. You can use the [Analyze API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/test-analyzer) for that purpose.

Comment: yes Ishan, I can do that but with simple query type, I cannot do a search for contains. e.g. musk@gmail.com in this case.

Comment: Since you are using `uax_url_email` tokenizer, the email is indexed is a single token. You cannot execute a contains query using simple query syntax. You'd have to use regexp queries that are supported through the lucene query syntax. This should work for your particular case.               **search=/.*musk@gmail.com/&queryType=full**                                           Take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-query-lucene-examples.

Answer (score 0):

So, here is the workaround that I have done. I had in my database email(s) containing uppercase letters like 'EMusk@gmail.com'
I had a requirement to be able to search contains as well as full search which means:
emusk@gmail.com, EMusk@gmail.com, musk@gmail.com should all return the result.
So, I did the following things:

1. Created a View and changed the email to Select LOWER(email) as
   email.
2. So, my Azure Search index contains all lowercase emails.
3. Then
   I am using /.*.*/&queryType=full to search the email.
   Example: /.*EMUSK@gmail.com.*/&queryType=full.